# Interpretion for Connect.Dnn.Koi.DnnSkinFile.AutoDetect error

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I've a DNN 8.0.3 site, with 2sxc 10.25.2 just installed. I had the old FAQ (v1) installed, then installed the latest (v2.x), deleted the old FAQ App.

Then when I created a new FAQ app I get the following (KOI?) error. I can go through and edit the FAQ template, data items and other aspects just fine. The browser console window doesn't show any related errors.

I'm guessing I need to add the Koi stuff to my stylesheet? Any other suggestions first?

Error: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' at Connect.Dnn.Koi.DnnSkinFile.AutoDetect() at Connect.Koi.Context.HttpContextState.TryToDetectTheCssFramework() at Connect.Koi.Context.HttpContextState.get_CssFramework() at Connect.Koi.Context.ToolsForCurrentState.get_Css() at Connect.Koi.Koi.Class(String classes) at ASP._Page_Portals_1_2sxc_FAQ__Categories_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\vashonbeprepared.org\httpdocs\Portals\1\2sxc\FAQ_Categories.cshtml:line 7 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at ASP._Page_Portals_1_2sxc_FAQ__FAQ_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\vhosts\vashonbeprepared.org\httpdocs\Portals\1\2sxc\FAQ_FAQ.cshtml:line 12 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 82 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in 
C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 91 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in 
C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 108 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.CmsBlock.Render() in 
C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\CmsBlock_Render.cs:line 54 
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I've not bothered to enable Fusion in the registry, but can.

THANKS!!!

Comment: I've Visual Studio 2019, but not Visual Studio 2017 any more. Could it be that my version of Web.helpers is out of sync with that used by the KOI build team??

Comment: I have added the koi.json file to my theme and that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that randomly pops up - must be fixed in main web.config. Pls check https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1595